# bitcored + vmware: disk space increases INCREDIBLY fast

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I installed ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 within a vm maschine from vmware. After downlading and installing bitcored (I did these steps: https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node) the blockchain starts to syncronize but keeps adding disk space incredibly fast.
Insight says the blockchain is 1 % synced and already takes 30gb+ (I just installed ubuntu and there is nothing more on this system). Maybe this is some error with cache/temp not beeing deleted after progressing a block or something?

If I let it run it creates 400gb+ until the virtual maschine crashes. After that, vmware is not able to start the vm again. (current bitcoin blockchain is <200 gb. I dont know why this thing needs to write 400gb+ of data to my disk space).

Opening "disks" on ubuntu says the system uses ~13gb (which should be right). Where does the other endless GB come from?

Any help is highly appeciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of the nature of the entire blockchain, and the virtual disks itself. 400Gb+ can be the blockchain obtained from the network, temporally persisted, and 13Gb seems to be the amount that is really persisted.

Those numbers are fine in orders of magnitude when operating a full bitcoin node. To control the grow of the space, maybe creating a fixed-size virtualbox will help

Comment: Looks like it was an vmware issue. Seems to work fine with virtual box. Thanks! :)